# import coding to a new tkinter from another file

Tags: python, import, tkinter

I have a file called `wckcalendar.py`.I want to import this calendar, to another tkinter `qw.py` which has a button.I wanted to display both the button and calendar from wckcalendar file on the same tkinter.

But i get error as:

```
  File "C:/Python27/qw.py", line 1, in <module>
    import wckCalendar
  File "C:/Python27\wckCalendar.py", line 115, in <module>
    root.mainloop()
NameError: name 'root' is not defined
>>>
```

Problem:I am not getting displayed my button and calendar on the same window.Please help!
qw.py

```
import wckCalendar
from wckCalendar import *
import Tkinter
class myproject(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent, master):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.button2()
        self.calendar()
        win(root, data)
    def button2(self):
        button2 = Tkinter.Button(self, text = "Ram")
        button2.grid(column=1,row=3)

    def win(parent, d):
        win = tk.Toplevel(parent)
        cal = Calendar(win, d)
app = myproject(None, None)
app.mainloop()
```

wckCalendar.py

```
import calendar
import Tkinter as tk
import datetime

class Data:
    def __init__(self):
        self.day_selected = 0
        self.month_selected = 0
        self.year_selected = 0
        self.day_name = 0
class Calendar(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, data, **config):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, cnf=config)
        self.data = data
        self.parent = parent
        self.cal = calendar.TextCalendar(calendar.SUNDAY)
        self.year = 2014
        self.month = 11
        self.wid = []
        self.day_selected = 1
        self.month_selected = self.month
        self.year_selected = self.year
        self.day_name = ''

        self.setup(self.year, self.month)

    def clear(self):
        for w in self.wid[:]:
            w.grid_forget()
            #w.destroy()
            self.wid.remove(w)

    def go_prev(self):
        if self.month > 1:
            self.month -= 1
        else:
            self.month = 12
            self.year -= 1
        #self.selected = (self.month, self.year)
        self.clear()
        self.setup(self.year, self.month)

    def go_next(self):
        if self.month < 12:
            self.month += 1
        else:
            self.month = 1
            self.year += 1

        #self.selected = (self.month, self.year)
        self.clear()
        self.setup(self.year, self.month)

    def selection(self, day, name):
        self.day_selected = day
        self.month_selected = self.month
        self.year_selected = self.year
        self.day_name = name

        self.data.day_selected = day
        self.data.month_selected = self.month
        self.data.year_selected = self.year
        self.data.day_name = name

        #self.selected = day
        self.clear()
        self.setup(self.year, self.month)

    def setup(self, y, m):
        left = tk.Button(self.parent, text='<', command=self.go_prev)
        self.wid.append(left)
        left.grid(row=0, column=1)

        header = tk.Label(self.parent, height=2, text='{}   {}'.format(calendar.month_abbr[m], str(y)))
        self.wid.append(header)
        header.grid(row=0, column=2, columnspan=3)

        right = tk.Button(self.parent, text='>', command=self.go_next)
        self.wid.append(right)
        right.grid(row=0, column=5)

        days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']
        for num, name in enumerate(days):
            t = tk.Label(self.parent, text=name[:3])
            self.wid.append(t)
            t.grid(row=1, column=num)

        for w, week in enumerate(self.cal.monthdayscalendar(y, m), 2):
            for d, day in enumerate(week):
                if day:
                    #print(calendar.day_name[day])
                    b = tk.Button(self.parent, width=1, text=day, command=lambda day=day:self.selection(day, calendar.day_name[(day-1) % 7]))
                    self.wid.append(b)
                    b.grid(row=w, column=d)

        sel = tk.Label(self.parent, height=2, text='{} {} {} {}'.format(
            self.day_name, calendar.month_name[self.month_selected], self.day_selected, self.year_selected))
        self.wid.append(sel)
        sel.grid(row=8, column=0, columnspan=7)

        ok = tk.Button(self.parent, width=5, text='OK', command='disabled')
        self.wid.append(ok)
        ok.grid(row=9, column=2, columnspan=3, pady=10)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # all the stuff not needed when importing Calendar into another module>
    def win(parent, d):
        win = tk.Toplevel(parent)
        cal = Calendar(win, d)
    data = Data()
    root = tk.Tk()
    win(root, data)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: what is `win(parent, d)` supposed to be doing?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham It will call the calendar!

Comment: but you are not using the function anywhere

Comment: @PadraicCunningham i m using the function in the first code!

Comment: in your first code you use root but never define it

Answer (score 1):

your last statement `root.mainloop()` is not indented correctly and will be run in the context of module import, that's not what you want

I saw some other problems in your code like local variables of function holding objects : they will be garbage collected after the function return